# How to export the user access level and user project name from azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I am able to export the access level of user from azure devops but please help me with the export of user project name from azure devops.

Answer (score 0):

To export the projects in an Azure DevOps Organization, there is no option to do that in Azure DevOps portal, your option is to use Azure DevOps REST API or Azure CLI to do that.

Azure DevOps REST API - [`Projects - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/Projects/List?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0
```

For more details, please refer to this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/Projects/List?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Azure CLI - [`az devops project list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/project?view=azure-cli-latest#az_devops_project_list)(to use this command successfully, please do the prerequisities [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops)):

```
az devops project list [--continuation-token]
                       [--detect {false, true}]
                       [--get-default-team-image-url {false, true}]
                       [--org]
                       [--query-examples]
                       [--skip]
                       [--state-filter {all, createPending, deleted, deleting, new, unchanged, wellFormed}]
                       [--subscription]
                       [--top]
```